# warning when run command sudo apt-get update

Tags: warnings, apt-get

```
Fetched 5,388 B in 9s (547 B/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/      precise/contrib amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_precise_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ precise/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_precise_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I rn apt-get update again and again it shows that warning. I am using ubuntu12.04lts and my kernel information are.                                                                                                                                                                                      Linux siva-pt130 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You /etc/apt/sources.list files contains a duplicate. Open it with an editor like vim and remove it. The run apt-get update again.

Answer (score 0):

I think virtualbox create new list folder so you can remove it using:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list~
```

then run :

```
sudo apt-get update
```